# How to aggregate similar columns inside a very long table?

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have quite a difficult problem that I don't have any idea how to approach it. I'll be glad to receive some advice.

I have a very long table which contains details about a specific house residents. Some of the columns are common for all the residents and some are individual. The distinction is being made by a set of numbers. For example - all fields containing 01 (CarMake01, Phone01 and so on) represent the first person. All fields containing 02 represent the second person and so on. Field without numbers are common (City, street and so on).

My goal is to run a query which takes this long table and creates a new table containing just the common fields and the fields containing a specific numbers (01, 02 and so on). Here is the code for the current table. I hope i'm clear enough. should I use pivot or some other function ?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FamiliesStageA](
    [Hhid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AssignedUser] [int] NULL,
    [Hhphone] [nvarchar](11) NULL,
    [FamilyName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [City] [int] NULL,
    [Street] [int] NULL,
    [HouseNum] [int] NULL,
    [Hhsize] [int] NULL,
    [NumCar] [int] NULL,
    [CarYear] [int] NULL,
    [CarMake01] [int] NULL,
    [CarMake02] [int] NULL,
    [CarMake03] [int] NULL,
    [CarMake04] [int] NULL,
    [CarMake05] [int] NULL,
    [CarModel01] [int] NULL,
    [CarModel02] [int] NULL,
    [CarModel03] [int] NULL,
    [CarModel04] [int] NULL,
    [CarModel05] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID01] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID02] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID03] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID04] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID05] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID06] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID07] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID08] [int] NULL,
    [PesonID09] [int] NULL,
    [PesonID10] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID11] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID12] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID13] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID14] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID15] [int] NULL,
    [Phone01] [int] NULL,
    [Phone02] [int] NULL,
    [Phone03] [int] NULL,
    [Phone04] [int] NULL,
    [Phone05] [int] NULL,
    [Phone06] [int] NULL,
    [Phone07] [int] NULL,
    [Phone08] [int] NULL,
    [Phone09] [int] NULL,
    [Phone10] [int] NULL,
    [Phone11] [int] NULL,
    [Phone12] [int] NULL,
    [Phone13] [int] NULL,
    [Phone14] [int] NULL,
    [Phone15] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName01] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName02] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName03] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName04] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName05] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName06] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName07] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName08] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName09] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName10] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName11] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName12] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName13] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName14] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName15] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome01] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome02] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome03] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome04] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome05] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome06] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome07] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome08] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome09] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome10] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome11] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome12] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome13] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome14] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome15] [int] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth01] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth02] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth03] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth04] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth05] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth06] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth07] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth08] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth09] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth10] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth11] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth12] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth13] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth14] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth15] [date] NULL,
    [License01] [int] NULL,
    [License02] [int] NULL,
    [License03] [int] NULL,
    [License04] [int] NULL,
    [License05] [int] NULL,
    [License06] [int] NULL,
    [License07] [int] NULL,
    [License08] [int] NULL,
    [License09] [int] NULL,
    [License10] [int] NULL,
    [License11] [int] NULL,
    [License12] [int] NULL,
    [License13] [int] NULL,
    [License14] [int] NULL,
    [License15] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode01] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode02] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode03] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode04] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode05] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode06] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode07] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode08] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode09] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode10] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode11] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode12] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode13] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode14] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode15] [int] NULL
```

Comment: Did not understand the question properly. What do you mean with "creates a new table containing just the common fields and the fields containing a specific numbers (01, 02 and so on)."? How should the output look like?

Answer (score 0):

This won't actually create the table, but it will provide you the data: I fixed a few spelling errors in your original code (PersonID, not PesonID), but otherwise it's the same.

Note that, since you didn't provide any sample data and I wasn't about to try to load it all, I haven't been able to test this against anything - review it for accuracy and let me know if there are any issues. If you don't need the temp table, comment it out and replace references to it with your actual table.

```
--DROP TABLE #FamiliesStageA 

CREATE TABLE #FamiliesStageA(
    [Hhid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AssignedUser] [int] NULL,
    [Hhphone] [nvarchar](11) NULL,
    [FamilyName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [City] [int] NULL,
    [Street] [int] NULL,
    [HouseNum] [int] NULL,
    [Hhsize] [int] NULL,
    [NumCar] [int] NULL,
    [CarYear] [int] NULL,
    [CarMake01] [int] NULL,
    [CarMake02] [int] NULL,
    [CarMake03] [int] NULL,
    [CarMake04] [int] NULL,
    [CarMake05] [int] NULL,
    [CarModel01] [int] NULL,
    [CarModel02] [int] NULL,
    [CarModel03] [int] NULL,
    [CarModel04] [int] NULL,
    [CarModel05] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID01] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID02] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID03] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID04] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID05] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID06] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID07] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID08] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID09] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID10] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID11] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID12] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID13] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID14] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID15] [int] NULL,
    [Phone01] [int] NULL,
    [Phone02] [int] NULL,
    [Phone03] [int] NULL,
    [Phone04] [int] NULL,
    [Phone05] [int] NULL,
    [Phone06] [int] NULL,
    [Phone07] [int] NULL,
    [Phone08] [int] NULL,
    [Phone09] [int] NULL,
    [Phone10] [int] NULL,
    [Phone11] [int] NULL,
    [Phone12] [int] NULL,
    [Phone13] [int] NULL,
    [Phone14] [int] NULL,
    [Phone15] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName01] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName02] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName03] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName04] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName05] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName06] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName07] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName08] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName09] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName10] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName11] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName12] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName13] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName14] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName15] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome01] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome02] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome03] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome04] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome05] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome06] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome07] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome08] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome09] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome10] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome11] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome12] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome13] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome14] [int] NULL,
    [SleepHome15] [int] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth01] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth02] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth03] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth04] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth05] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth06] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth07] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth08] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth09] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth10] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth11] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth12] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth13] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth14] [date] NULL,
    [DateOfBirth15] [date] NULL,
    [License01] [int] NULL,
    [License02] [int] NULL,
    [License03] [int] NULL,
    [License04] [int] NULL,
    [License05] [int] NULL,
    [License06] [int] NULL,
    [License07] [int] NULL,
    [License08] [int] NULL,
    [License09] [int] NULL,
    [License10] [int] NULL,
    [License11] [int] NULL,
    [License12] [int] NULL,
    [License13] [int] NULL,
    [License14] [int] NULL,
    [License15] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode01] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode02] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode03] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode04] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode05] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode06] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode07] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode08] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode09] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode10] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode11] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode12] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode13] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode14] [int] NULL,
    [MainTransportMode15] [int] NULL)


SELECT 
    Family.HHID,
    AssignedUser,
    HHPhone,
    FamilyName,
    City,
    Street,
    HouseNum,
    HHSize,
    NumCar,
    CarYear,
    CarMake.CarMake,
    CarModel.CarModel,
    PersonID.PersonID,
    Phone.Phone,
    FirstName.FirstName,
    SleepHome.SleepHome,
    DateOfBirth.DateOfBirth,
    License.License,
    MainTransportMode.MainTransportMode
FROM 
    #FamiliesStageA Family
     INNER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 1 AS Number UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION 
        SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION 
        SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15  
      ) Nums ON 1=1
     LEFT JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            HHID,
            RIGHT(UP.COL,2) AS PersonNum,
            CarMake
        FROM #FamiliesStageA
        UNPIVOT
            (CarMake FOR COL IN 
              ([CarMake01], [CarMake02], [CarMake03], [CarMake04], [CarMake05])
              ) UP
      ) CarMake ON 
        Family.HHID = CarMake.Hhid AND
        Nums.Number = CarMake.PersonNum
     LEFT JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            HHID,
            RIGHT(UP.COL,2) AS PersonNum,
            CarModel
        FROM #FamiliesStageA
        UNPIVOT
            (CarModel FOR COL IN 
              (
              [CarModel01], [CarModel02], [CarModel03], [CarModel04], [CarModel05])
              ) UP
      ) CarModel ON 
        Family.HHID = CarModel.Hhid AND
        Nums.Number = CarModel.PersonNum
     LEFT JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            HHID,
            RIGHT(UP.COL,2) AS PersonNum,
            PersonID
        FROM #FamiliesStageA
        UNPIVOT
            (PersonID FOR COL IN 
              (
              [PersonID01], [PersonID02], [PersonID03], [PersonID04], [PersonID05],
              [PersonID06], [PersonID07], [PersonID08], [PersonID09], [PersonID10],
              [PersonID11], [PersonID12], [PersonID13], [PersonID14], [PersonID15])
              ) UP
      ) PersonID ON 
        Family.HHID = PersonID.Hhid AND
        Nums.Number = PersonID.PersonNum
     LEFT JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            HHID,
            RIGHT(UP.COL,2) AS PersonNum,
            Phone
        FROM #FamiliesStageA
        UNPIVOT
            (Phone FOR COL IN 
              (
              [Phone01], [Phone02], [Phone03], [Phone04], [Phone05],
              [Phone06], [Phone07], [Phone08], [Phone09], [Phone10],
              [Phone11], [Phone12], [Phone13], [Phone14], [Phone15])
              ) UP
      ) Phone ON 
        Family.HHID = Phone.Hhid AND
        Nums.Number = Phone.PersonNum
     LEFT JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            HHID,
            RIGHT(UP.COL,2) AS PersonNum,
            FirstName
        FROM #FamiliesStageA
        UNPIVOT
            (FirstName FOR COL IN 
              (
              [FirstName01], [FirstName02], [FirstName03], [FirstName04], [FirstName05],
              [FirstName06], [FirstName07], [FirstName08], [FirstName09], [FirstName10],
              [FirstName11], [FirstName12], [FirstName13], [FirstName14], [FirstName15])
              ) UP
      ) FirstName ON 
        Family.HHID = FirstName.Hhid AND
        Nums.Number = FirstName.PersonNum
     LEFT JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            HHID,
            RIGHT(UP.COL,2) AS PersonNum,
            SleepHome
        FROM #FamiliesStageA
        UNPIVOT
            (SleepHome FOR COL IN 
              (
              [SleepHome01], [SleepHome02], [SleepHome03], [SleepHome04], [SleepHome05],
              [SleepHome06], [SleepHome07], [SleepHome08], [SleepHome09], [SleepHome10],
              [SleepHome11], [SleepHome12], [SleepHome13], [SleepHome14], [SleepHome15])
              ) UP
      ) SleepHome ON 
        Family.HHID = SleepHome.Hhid AND
        Nums.Number = SleepHome.PersonNum
     LEFT JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            HHID,
            RIGHT(UP.COL,2) AS PersonNum,
            DateOfBirth
        FROM #FamiliesStageA
        UNPIVOT
            (DateOfBirth FOR COL IN 
              (
              [DateOfBirth01], [DateOfBirth02], [DateOfBirth03], [DateOfBirth04], [DateOfBirth05],
              [DateOfBirth06], [DateOfBirth07], [DateOfBirth08], [DateOfBirth09], [DateOfBirth10],
              [DateOfBirth11], [DateOfBirth12], [DateOfBirth13], [DateOfBirth14], [DateOfBirth15])
              ) UP
      ) DateOfBirth ON 
        Family.HHID = DateOfBirth.Hhid AND
        Nums.Number = DateOfBirth.PersonNum
     LEFT JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            HHID,
            RIGHT(UP.COL,2) AS PersonNum,
            License
        FROM #FamiliesStageA
        UNPIVOT
            (License FOR COL IN 
              (
              [License01], [License02], [License03], [License04], [License05],
              [License06], [License07], [License08], [License09], [License10],
              [License11], [License12], [License13], [License14], [License15])
              ) UP
      ) License ON 
        Family.HHID = License.Hhid AND
        Nums.Number = License.PersonNum
     LEFT JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            HHID,
            RIGHT(UP.COL,2) AS PersonNum,
            MainTransportMode
        FROM #FamiliesStageA
        UNPIVOT
            (MainTransportMode FOR COL IN 
              (
              [MainTransportMode01], [MainTransportMode02], [MainTransportMode03], [MainTransportMode04], [MainTransportMode05],
              [MainTransportMode06], [MainTransportMode07], [MainTransportMode08], [MainTransportMode09], [MainTransportMode10],
              [MainTransportMode11], [MainTransportMode12], [MainTransportMode13], [MainTransportMode14], [MainTransportMode15])
      ) UP
      ) MainTransportMode ON 
        Family.HHID = MainTransportMode.Hhid AND
        Nums.Number = MainTransportMode.PersonNum
```